# Запись данных из COM-порта в файл

Tags: c#

Не пишутся данные из COM порта в файл, он остается пустым, хотя данные приходят. Не ясно в чем дело. Если заменить sp.ReadLine() на рандомную строку данные пишутся и сохраняются.

```
class Program
{
    static void ListeningComPort(SerialPort sp)
    {
        string mydocpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        string str = "";
        using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(mydocpath + @"\inputDataOfCOM.txt")) {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    str = sp.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(str);
                    outputFile.Write(str);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
            finally {
                outputFile.Close();
            }

        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SerialPort sp = new SerialPort("COM6", 9600);
        sp.Open();
        ListeningComPort(sp);
        sp.Close();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Хм. А правильное ли значение у `sp.NewLine`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решилось с добавлением `outputFile.Flush()` после `outputFile.Write(str)`.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы получить данные из COM-порта, вам нужно подписаться на отдельное событие: *DataReceived* и уже через него получат данные. 
Данное событие, как видно из названия, будет вызываться при поступление данных.

Детальный пример доступен в официальной документации:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_6